# Is a war file deployment required for changes in java file in a worklight project?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, war, worklight-server

Is a war file deployment required for changes in java file in the server folder in a worklight project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Any changes done under the your-project\server folder trigger a re-generation of the .war file, where such data resides. This updated .war file then needs to be re-deployed to the application server.